# Is it impossible upload file in the different region from the region of s3 bucket? (IllegalLocationConstraintException)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed my django project using AWS Elastic beanstalk and S3,
and I tried to upload the profile avatar but it shows Server Error(500)

My Sentry log shows me,
"An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the PutObject operation: The eu-south-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to."

I think this error appeared
because I put my bucket on eu-south-1 but I try to access it and to create a new object in Seoul, Korea.

Also, the AWS document said IllegalLocationConstraintException indicates that you are trying to access a bucket from a different Region than where the bucket exists. To avoid this error, use the --region option. For example: aws s3 cp awsexample.txt s3://testbucket/ --region ap-east-1.
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html)

but this solution might be just for when upload a file from AWS CLI...

I tried to change my bucket policy by adding this but doesn't work.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{BucketName}/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know what should I do and why they do not allow access from other regions?
How to allow access to create, update and remove an object in my bucket from all around the world?
This is my first deployment please help me

Answer (score 0):

Is your Django Elastic Beanstalk instance in a different region from the S3 bucket? If so, you need to set the `AWS_S3_REGION_NAME` setting as documented [here](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html).

Comment: No Elastic Beanstalk is in the same region as the S3 bucket. but I guess when the user is in a different region from 'eu-south-1', maybe AWS doesn't allow to put a new object in the bucket. I tried already to set AWS_S3_REGION_NAME but the problem is the same.

Comment: The user shouldn't have any impact on what region ID the server uses to communicate with S3. Maybe you should include more details about what you are doing exactly. Are you using the Django S3 integration, or uploading directly from a web browser to S3 somehow? Do you have any code you can show?

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I mean that this problem appears when I upload a file or update o remove it on the website like a user. It works well when I upload the static file using the awsebcli. https://github.com/bamichoi/cineacca this is my repo of this project. maybe I have to add something to settings.py o change some configuration on the aws console.

Comment: Thank you It works! I tried adding AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = "public-read-write" and AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "eu-south-1" and it works!